# What is texture aliasing and is there any specific "data-structure" to avoid it

Tags: antialiasing

Is there any specific difference from normal aliasing and specifically **texture aliasing?**

Also, is there any specific data structure which can be used to avoid aliasing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by "normal" aliasing?  Aliasing is the result of under-sampling: i.e being given a signal with a high frequency (temporal and/or spatial) that is being sampled too infrequently (it needs to be sampled at a rate exceeding 2x its maximum frequency OR band-limited/pre-filtered until its max frequency is < 1/2 the sampling rate).

With texture data, *the* common pre-filtering approach is to use MIP maps (see [Lance Williams' "Pyramidal Parametrics"](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/800059.801126).

FWIW I like to explain aliasing by the following:
Imagine you work for a an office-based company (i.e pre covid WFH etc), and are at your desk solidly, 9~5, apart from a lunch break and a 15 min coffee break at 10:30.
The CEO take a regular stroll around the office at 10:35 and thus always sees you in the kitchen, rather than at your desk.
Because she is under-sampling your 'signal', she thus assumes you are never working.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I was actually a bit confused about aliasing itself. That is why I framed the question poorly.